# How to find the number of numerals of the fractional part

Tags: c++, numbers

I put a number and the code give me a how many digits in fractional part(after the decimal point). (write with cin)
For example: input - 0.234.
output - 3.
I tried to write a code (i wrote it below), but code always gives me a number 6.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
int countFractionalDigits(double n) {
    std::string n_str = std::to_string(n);
    size_t decimalPos = n_str.find('.');
    if (decimalPos != std::string::npos) {
        std::string fractionalPart = n_str.substr(decimalPos + 1); 
        return fractionalPart.length();
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    double number; 
    std::cin>> number; 
    int Digits = countFractionalDigits(number);
    std::cout << Digits;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you seem to have the code for doing what your question title says, so what is the question ?

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but number is never initialized, so the program could do anything. More to the point, I'm not sure that your `countFractionalDigits` will work, or even that it is well defined what is meant by fractional digits here. The machine uses a base 2 floating point representation, so the number of decimal fractional digits may not be what you'd expect.

Comment: I accidentally erased a line with std::cin>> number;
When i run the programm, the programm always give me a number six.

Comment: `fractionalPart.length()` returns the 6 digits you get when using `std::to_string`

Comment: `0.234` cannot be exactly represented in any floating point type with a binary (base 2) significand, since expressing it as a sum of negative powers of two gives an infinite series.   So the value stored in a floating point variable will be either the next or previous value that the floating point type *can* represent.  That representable value is close to *but not exactly* equal to `0.234`.     Your code is calculating a property of that representable value (possibly with some truncation, due to default settings of how floating point values are formatted).

Answer (score 1):

Using floating point numbers is the wrong approach. You might get it working but it is too complicated. Consider that user input is a sequence of characters, a string. There is no need to let `cin` parse those characters to a `double`, then convert it to a `std::string` to find the `.`. You can find the dot directly in the user input:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
auto pos = input.find('.');
....
```

If later you want to get the `double` from the user input you can still use a string stream and parse the number via `>>` just as you do it now via `std::cin >> number` (but extracting from a stringstream rather than from `std::cin`).

You could use a debugger, or add additional `std::cout` in your code to see why the result is always `6`. For example for input `3.12` this:

```
std::string n_str = std::to_string(n);
std::cout << n_str  << "\n";
```

Will print `3.123000`. More details and examples that show the same behavior (6 digits) you can find here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string.

The lesson to take away is to use a debugger, to test every single step of your algorithm (it was the first step in the function that went wrong, so no need to consider the rest), and to read documentation of functions you are using.

Comment: I like this approach. Here's an example implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/7T5bWTjYc

Answer (score 0):

`fractionalPart.length()` returns the 6 digits you get when using `std::to_string`. You could consider using a `std::ostringstream` and set the precision to what you'd like instead. It's no guarantee that you won't get a surprise though since floating point math is not precise.

Example:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::size_t countFractionalDigits(double n) {
    std::ostringstream n_str;
    n_str.precision(15);
    n_str << n;
    size_t decimalPos = n_str.str().find('.');
    if (decimalPos != std::string::npos) {
        std::string fractionalPart = n_str.str().substr(decimalPos + 1); 
        return fractionalPart.length();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or a bit simplified:

```cpp
int countFractionalDigits(double n) {
    std::ostringstream n_str;
    n_str.precision(15);
    n_str << n;
    const auto& str = n_str.str();
    size_t decimalPos = str.find('.');
    if (decimalPos != std::string::npos) {
        return str.length() - decimalPos - 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```